# iOS in app purchases. is server space comes under in app purchases?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an app where free users get less storage space on my server, and premium users get more storage space on my server. All functionality inside the app is the same. But if a free user passes their storage limit, their files will no longer sync.

Is Storage Space on a server considered "content, functionality, or services"? Or is it considered "physical goods/goods and services used outside the app"?

Can I use third party pay for this or specify weblink ?

Comment: I'd assume it'd be content, functionality, and services

Answer (score 0):

No, don't use any third party payment gateway for this purpose. Apple will reject your app if you do so. All the digital content information should be buy using in-app purchase only. I'm not sure what exactly your requirement but from what I understood, create a product identifier in in-app purchase and maintain flag in your backend for knowing whether that user is paid or free user. Update that flag when in-app purchase is completed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I am not selling magzins or or any virtual currency..Its a storage access on server and my android app will also use the same storage space...I can see for some apps for selling tshirts,tickets (tickets are in the app only..they dont issue any physical paper for this)they used the external links and third party payments...